# Images in Nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Faced with the problem of rendering a lot of images in nextjs
When I don't set `position: relative` for parent and `position: absolute` for child and set clear `height` and `width` values for the Image itself, I can't increase or decrease the image via css depending on the viewport change.

```
<Image src={partners.img} width={50} height={50} alt="partners"/>

//css
.partnersWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.partnerItem {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But when I set `layout={'fill'}` for Image, the images get the size I need, nevertheless, they begin to overlap each other.
Instead of switching to other lines. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div className={styles.partnersWrapper}>
     <Grid container columnSpacing={3} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 4, md: 12 }}>
        {partnersData.map((partners) => (
          <Grid item xs={2} sm={2} md={2.4} key={partners.id}>
            <div className={styles.partnerItem}>
              <Image
                src={partners.img}
                layout={"fill"}
                alt="partners"
                key={partners.id}
              />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
    </Grid>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fill` layout make sure that the parent container `partnerItem` has `position: relative`, to fit the container width and height.

Comment: so I wrote that parent - position: relative=)

Comment: in your code, you have above `partnerItem` is `absolute` not `relative`

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Thanks a lot